# GraphQL Error when switching from buildSchema to GraphSQLSchema

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying a simple GraphQL protoype I have a simple query working ...

```
import {
  graphql,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString
} from 'graphql'

...
var schema = buildSchema(`
type Partner {
    name:String!, 
    id:ID,
    print: String
}
type Query {
    getPartner(name: String!, id: ID) : Partner 
}
```

I'm trying to now use the pragmatic approach of building the schema ...

```
let partnerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Partner',
  fields: {
    name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    print: { type: graphql.GraphQLString}
  }
})

let queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    getPartner: {
      type: partnerType,
      args: {
       name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
       id: { type: graphql.GraphQLID }
     },
     //resolve: function(_, { id }) {
     resolve() {
       //as a test remove args
       return new Partner("test", 1)
     }
   } 
  }
})
```

Obviously I am missing something here - I'm getting an error

```
{
 "errors": [
   {
     "message": "The type of Query.getPartner(name:) must be Input 
Type but got: undefined.\n\nThe type of Query.getPartner(id:) must be 
Input Type but got: undefined.\n\nThe type of Partner.name must be 
Output Type but got: undefined.\n\nThe type of Partner.id must be 
Output Type but got: undefined.\n\nThe type of Partner.print must be 
Output Type but got: undefined."
   }
 ]
}
```

I get that somehow the input params are not being passed to the query ?
Any ideas ? By The way I am getting the same error with the example code http://graphql.org/graphql-js/constructing-types/

Comment: How are you defining the graphql variable?

Comment: `import {
  graphql,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString
} from 'graphql'`

Comment: @DanielRearden thanks, that was the issue !! Much appreciated !